# Invert match in regex

Tags: regex

Is there any way (or possible) to invert match a pattern (not a pre-given word) using regex?

e.g.

Input string:

```
a:b, c:d, a:b1,s:sad
```

The pattern is

```
a:[^,]+,?
```

This pattern matches "a:b," and "a:b1," in the string. Could I replace/invert match the remain part, i.e. " c:d," and "s:sad" without using grep -v -e?

e.g. continue, demo output replacing the remain with "[TAG]":

```
a:b,[TAG], a:b1,[TAG]
```

The [^pattern] or (?!pattern) trick fails and grep with -e -v options are not allowed here.

Thanks!

Comment: You could write another regex which captures the other strings, i.e. `[^a]:[^,]+,?`

Comment: With PCRE/Perl, you can use [`a:[^,]+,?(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!a:[^,]+,?).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/xE4iU6/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[^,:]+(?<!\ba):[^,]+,?
```

You can simply use this with `grep -P` .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/25

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
/((a:[^,]+,?\s?)(((?!a:[^,]+).)+(,|$))+)/\2[TAG]\5/g
```

will replace

```
a:b, c:d, a:b1,s:sad
```

with

```
a:b, [TAG], a:b1,[TAG]
```

But I'm not sure I understood your comment about (?!pattern) not working. I am testing at https://regex101.com/.

Comment: Thanks! I put the pattern directly into (?!) and it doesn't work. It seems I need to group the pattern more carefully.